# Why is it if [1,2,2,4]*[y,z]=[1,2] than why is [1,2,2,4]*[y+8,z-4]=[1,2] as well?

Tags: matrices

> Take the numbers $y=1$ and $z=0$. Without any calculation, explain why 
>   $$
> \mathbf{A} 
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> y+8 \\
> z-4
> \end{array}
> \right] = \mathbf{b}
> $$
>   where $b= \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> 1 \\2
> \end{array} 
> \right]$

A= [1,2,2,4] ,which is a 4*4 matrix

[Working out so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zlPB.png)
I have done the working for it but i am struggling to explain why it works without doing any calculation

Comment: I think your solution looks good. I don't know how else one would approach this. Note also that in order to solve this problem, one should see the a-part and its solution. That's why it's usually not a good idea to post only the b-part of a question here.

Comment: I apologies for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-b & a \end{bmatrix}^T$ are orthogonal to each other.

The row space of $A$ is spanned by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$, hence $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}^T$ is in the nullspace of $A$. Similarly , $4\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1\end{bmatrix}^T$ is in the nullspace  of $A$ as well.

A particular solution plus a nullspace element would be another solution of the linear system.